# How do I properly close JGit?

Tags: android, jgit

I'm using `org.eclipse.jgit:3.7.1.201504261725-r` on Android 7.1.2.

I'm creating JGit's `Git` this way:

```
repo = FileRepositoryBuilder()
    .setGitDir(File(gitDir))
    .findGitDir()
    .build()
...
repo.create()
...
git = Git(repo)
```

Then I'm pulling from remote repo with:

```
git.pull().setCredentialsProvider(auth).call()
```

And then I'm closing jgit:

```
git.close()
repo?.close()
```

The problem is, after pull is performed Android's Profiler shows that a single connection left open and sends small chunks of data roughly every 5 seconds.

[image]

Also I'm getting more and more connections each time I'm performing a pull:

[image]

The question is -- how do I properly close jgit to make it close all connections as soon as `git.close()` is called?

Comment: The version of JGit you are using is more than seven years old. I'd suggest to upgrade to a recent version of JGit, 6.2 is current.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann, I'm using the latest jgit version possible to run on Android API level 21. Modern jgit uses java language features not supported on Android.

Comment: To get a recent version of jgit you can try to remove the code that uses classes not available on Android as shown by the https://github.com/yappy/ajgit project (also an outdated project).

Comment: The code to close JGit looks good. I haven't seen JGit running anything in the background after returning from a command, except running GC (which doesn't open connections). Can you find out the target of the connection?

Comment: I assume this is the same IP that was used to pull from:
`IP 10.131.23.31.54315 > 172.65.251.78.https: Flags [.], ack 1, win 389, length 0`.  Anyway, answer I posted below solves problem for me, so I'll just leave it be and maybe will look for proper solution later. @RüdigerHerrmann, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution: keep interactions w/ JGit in a separate process

```
<service
    android:name=".GitOpsService"
    android:process=":git_ops"/>
```

and completely kill `Service` after all git operations is done

```
val myPid = android.os.Process.myPid()
android.os.Process.killProcess(myPid)
```

This solution closes all jgit's connections and also destroys everything else created in Service's process.

On the other hand, I still don't know how to make *JGit* clean all it's mess.